# Составление правильного SQL запроса с двумя условиями

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго вечера товарищи! Пишется некая система для заработка. Вот этот запрос выбирает матрицу, у которой меньше всего участников :

```
prepare('SELECT поля для выбора FROM cp_matrices WHERE users_paid + users_reserved < 12 ORDER BY users_paid + users_reserved ASC LIMIT 1');
```

**users_paid** - сколько человек оплатило
**users_reserved** - сколько человек забронировало место

В каждой матрице может быть максимально **users_paid + users_reserved = 12** человек. Сейчас алгоритм выбирает ту матрицу, в которой меньше всего человек, однако мне нужно чтобы выбиралась матрица в которой меньше **трёх** человек(**users_paid + users_reserved < 3**), а если такой нет - выберем ту матрицу, в которой наименьшее число человек, в приоритете более ранняя матрица.

Помогите пожалуйста сформировать правильный запрос с такими условиями.

Comment: рассуждайте терминами sql. субд может выбрать вам набор данных, которые соответствуют некоторому условию. количество соответствующих условию строк может быть большим. выберете сначала те, что нужны, затем отсортируйте их по тому критерию, который вам нужен, а затем уже ограничивайте лимитом. просто вы пытаетесь сразу все сделать, решайте задачу последовательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если лучше более поздняя матрица, но с 4-мя людьми, чем более ранняя, но с 5-ю, то

```
SELECT поля для выбора 
FROM cp_matrices 
ORDER BY users_paid + users_reserved ASC, creation_time ASC
LIMIT 1
```

если нет -

```
SELECT поля для выбора 
FROM cp_matrices 
WHERE users_paid + users_reserved < 3
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT поля для выбора 
ORDER BY creation_time ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Я возможно не до конца расписал вопрос : каждой матрице присваивается уникальный номер(ID через auto increment) так что запрос просто смотрит все записи начиная с меньшего ID и кончая большим. Матрица, которая ближе всех к началу и имеет меньше трёх человек(главное меньше) - будет выбрана, а дальше если таких матриц нет - выбираем ту, что ближе к началу и у неё меньше остальных матриц человек.